# Excluding a jar from tomcat/lib directory

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

There is a jar **javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar**(version 3.0.1-b08)  in my `web app/web-inf/lib` directory. But there is an older version of this jar **el-api.jar** in `tomcat/lib` directory. When I run my application it gives error as:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
>     org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:87)

I am using Tomcat version 7.

I want to ask how can I tell Tomcat or my application to exclude the tomcat version of above mentioned jar(i.e. el-api.jar in tomcat/lib) and to include jar present in my web app/WEB-INF/lib(i.e. javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar) formy application?

If I delete this el-api.jar from tomcat/lib then my application runs fine but then there is problem with tomcat running.

Comment: Assuming your not using ant or maven in your project as their scripts can be modified to exclude your lib from your WAR, this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/317901/tomcat-possible-to-exclude-jars-during-app-deployment) and answer might help you out - looks a little painful though

Comment: What are you using to create the war file?

Comment: @JGlass: I am using maven as build tool.

Comment: @gdegani: I am using maven to package it as war.

Comment: I wonder why somebody has marked it to close?

Comment: Are you defining the EL version you need in your pom.xml file? If your getting a class not found exception I don't the old version is the problem. How are you putting the correct jar in web app/web-inf/lib? Are you manually doing that or is it through your POM.xml?

Comment: If you are using maven to create the war, you should also set the scope for that dependency ( javax... ) to provided. The scope "provided" tells maven to add the jar to the class path during the compilation, but it will be excluded  from the final artifact.

Comment: Looks like it might be back in opened state, did you get things working with @gdegani advice?

Comment: @gdegani: scope was set to provided earlier. But then due to PROVIDED it was taking el jar from tomcat/lib which is a old version as according to my application. So I removed PROVIDED scope but still it is taking el jar from tomcat/lib, not from myapplication/ web-inf/ lib.

Comment: Set the scope to provided and use a dependencyManagement entry to fix the version for the  library.

Comment: @aLearner, were you able to solve this problem?